# Cannot detect certain value in column

Tags: python, pandas

I try to make a function to detect if a column has certain value but it returns `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` and 
Even if i check this it returns false, `'yes' in peep['anxiety'] Out[58]: False` i thought it checks if there's value 'yes' in the column

```
if (peep['anxiety']=='yes'):
    print('correct')
else :
    print('incorrect')
```

Comment: Please add that this question is about pandas.

Comment: You're asking if a column equals a single value which is why it throws an error.

Comment: @smartse oh okay, so what should it be then?

Comment: if value in list(series): works, but there's probably a better way...

Comment: @potatostudent do you want to check whether 'anxiety' column has a value 'yes' or not ?

Comment: @potatostudent You need to explain what you are trying to achieve. It is not clear from this question because you have not provided the full context. You might have an X/Y problem here, where you're asking about how to fix your solution, instead of how to solve your original problem. What is the problem this code is trying to solve? What is `peep` referring to here? Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: if ```peep['angxiety']``` is a list, why dont you do if (```'yes' in peep['angxiety']```)?

Comment: @Rika it is not a list, it is a `Series`. Doing `in` will check for the **indexes**, not **values**

Comment: @AkashKarnatak yes i do

Comment: you can use `peep['new_column'] = np.where(peep['anxiety']=='yes','Correct','Incorrect')`

Comment: @MihaiChelaru i'm trying to detect in my dataframe (peep) if in its column (anxiety) it has value 'yes' i just made that very simple code that i thought would work but did not work..

Comment: @anky the new_column values are all incorrect

Comment: even when `peep['anxiety']=='yes'` is True? can you check if it is an issue with case `yes v/s Yes` or leading or trailing space. Ideally you should take the approach the link to the duplicate has

Comment: @anky yes, even when `peep['anxiety']=='yes'` is True somehow it returns all False. yeah i think i will just try another way like in that link to the duplicate

Comment: Try `"yes" in peep["anxiety"]` inside the `np.where`. There might be extra spaces or something like that so it always fails

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether 'yes' is in peep['anxiety'] column then you can use `unique()` method of pd.Series. It returns a list of unique values of the specified Series. Now you can check whether 'yes' is there in this list using `in` operator,

```
if 'yes' in peep['anxiety'].unique():
    print('correct')
else:
    print('incorrect')
```

***Edit:***

@potatostudent's recent comment

> i want to check if the column in series contains 'yes' values which if
>   the if condition is fulfilled i want to to replace that 'yes' value
>   with 'has anxiety' value

Then you should try this

```
peep[peep['anxiety'] == 'yes'] = 'has anxiety'
```

Comment: using unique might work but isn't a great solution as it doesn't help OP understand what the problem is or why it works.

Comment: i tried but it should be printing correct.. there's anxiety value in peep dataframe column..

Comment: But that's not what you are checking @potatostudent You are checking if there is the value `"yes"` in the column `"anxiety"` of the dataframe `peep`

Comment: @Tomerikoo you are right but i'm kind of confused how to check it

Comment: @Tomerikoo i want to check if the column in series contains 'yes' values which if the if condition is fulfilled i want to to replace that 'yes' value with 'has anxiety' value

Comment: @potatostudent then you should update your question

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
if 'yes' in peep['anxiety'].values:
    print('correct')
else :
    print('incorrect')
```